# Inyección de dependencias c# error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Tengo un problema al intentar hacer una inyección de dependencias en C# cuando ejecuto me da el siguiente error.
**Startup**

> System.AggregateException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.IConverterHelper Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.ConverterHelper': Unable to resolve service for type 'EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.CombosHelper' while attempting to activate 'EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.ConverterHelper'.)
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at EstiloPlusWeb.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Proyectos\EstiloPlus\EstiloPlus\EstiloPlusWeb\Program.cs:line 16

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]

> Inner Exception 1:
> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.IConverterHelper Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.ConverterHelper': Unable to resolve service for type 'EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.CombosHelper' while attempting to activate 'EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.ConverterHelper'.

> Inner Exception 2:
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.CombosHelper' while attempting to activate 'EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.ConverterHelper'.

Tengo las siguientes clases, interfas, startup

**startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddScoped<ICombosHelper, CombosHelper>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddScoped<IConverterHelper, ConverterHelper>();

    }
```

**ConverterHelper**

```
    namespace EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers
{
    public class ConverterHelper : IConverterHelper
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly CombosHelper _combosHelper;

        public ConverterHelper(ApplicationDbContext context, CombosHelper  combosHelper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _combosHelper = combosHelper;
        }


        public EmpleadoViewModel ToEmpleadoViewModel(Empleado empleado)
        {
            return new EmpleadoViewModel
            {
                Nombre = empleado.Nombre,
                Apellido = empleado.Apellido,
                Cedula = empleado.Cedula,
                Direccion = empleado.Direccion,
                Celular = empleado.Celular,
                Email = empleado.Email,
                FechaIngreso = empleado.FechaIngreso,
                Categoria = empleado.Categoria,
                CategoriaId = empleado.Categoria.Id,
                Categorias = _combosHelper.GetComboCategorias()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**IConverterHelper**

```
    namespace EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers
{
    public interface IConverterHelper
    {
        Models.ViewsModels.EmpleadoViewModel ToEmpleadoViewModel(Empleado empleado);
    }
}
```

**comboHelper**

```
   namespace EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers
{
    public class CombosHelper : ICombosHelper
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public CombosHelper(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetComboCategorias()
        {
            var list = _context.Categoria.Select(pt => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = pt.Descripcion,
                Value = $"{pt.Id}"
            })
                .OrderBy(pt => pt.Text)
                .ToList();
            list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "[Seleccione la categoría..]",
                Value = "0"
            });
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

**IComboHelper**

```
namespace EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers
{
    public interface ICombosHelper
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetComboCategorias();
    }
}
```

La verdad que no estoy entendiendo cúal es el motivo por el que me lanza ese error.
Pueden ayudarme ?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luego de montar una prueba y reproducir el error, encontré que el problema está en la clase `ConverterHelper`.

El parámetro `combosHelper` lo declaras del tipo `CombosHelper` y debería ser `ICombosHelper`.

```
public class ConverterHelper : IConverterHelper
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    //Cambia el tipo aquí |
    //                    V
    private readonly ICombosHelper _combosHelper;

    //                             y tambien cambialo aquí    |
    //                                                        V
    public ConverterHelper(ApplicationDbContext context, ICombosHelper combosHelper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _combosHelper = combosHelper;
    }
```

Comment: Efectivamente era allli, el error decia que no se podia resolver CombosHelper >  _"Unable to resolve service for type 'EstiloPlusWeb.Helpers.CombosHelper'"_

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente por tu tiempo y preocupación, estoy incursionando en esta tecnología y la verdad que hay un montón de cosas que cometo errores. MIL GRACIAS NUEVAMENTE

Comment: Paciencia y perseverancia @MarceloPírez, en mi opinión cometiendo errores es cuando más aprendemos.